# Force reload route/state on link click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application, angularjs-routing, ngroute

Currently I'm doing something like this

```
link.on('click', function () {
    if (link.attr('href') !== $route.current.originalPath)
        return;
    $route.reload();
});
```

I'm not aware of side effects but I guess there can be some.

Is there more straightforward way to handle this in ngRoute, e.g. through `$location`?

What is the way to do the same thing in UI Router when the app will be updated to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could get tranformed to below change `$route.reload()` to `$state.reload()`

**Code**

```
link.on('click', function () {
    if (link.attr('href') !== $route.current.originalPath)
        return;
    //though this will not reload the controller content
    $state.reload(); //will force to reload state..
    $scope.$apply(); //needed here to tell angular js to run digest cycle.
});
```

From [**git-hub issue**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/582) it seems like `$state.reload()` reload the state but controller doesn't get re-instantiate. For that you need to use below code instead of `$state.reload()`

```
$state.transitionTo('tab.locations', $state.$current.params, { 
  reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true 
});
```

Comment: That's a good point, I believe I did $apply() in my original code, and sure, it is necessary here.

Comment: @estus yes..thats neccesary..any angular code called `externally`(out of angular context) need to tell angular to updated those changes(to reflect the bindings.)

Answer (score 8):

With UI-Router we have a set of options, and one of them is **`{reload: true}`**

#### [go(to, params, options)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

> - `location - {boolean=true|string=}` - If true will update the url in the location bar, if false will not. If string, must be "replace",
>     which will update url and also replace last history record.
> - `inherit - {boolean=true},` If true will inherit url parameters from current url.
> - `relative - {object=$state.$current}`, When transitioning with relative path (e.g '^'), defines which state to be relative from.
> - `notify - {boolean=true}`, If true will broadcast $stateChangeStart and $stateChangeSuccess events.
> - `reload (v0.2.5) - {boolean=false},` If true will force transition even if the state or params have not changed, aka a reload of the same
>     state. It differs from reloadOnSearch because you'd use this when you
>     want to force a reload when everything is the same, including search
>     params.

So we can force state reload with:

```
$state.go("stateName", stateParams, {reload: true});
```

Comment: Didn't have a chance to embrace 0.2.5, that's beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be the shortest way with UI-router :

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
```

or you can do this :

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
       reload: true,
       inherit: false,
       notify: true
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Ui.Router**:

```js
link.on('click', function (event) {
    if (link.attr('href') !== $route.current.originalPath)
        return;
  
    event.preventDefault();
    
    return $scope.$apply(function() {
      return $state.reload(); // $state.go($state.current.name, $stateParams, { inherit: false, reload: true, notify: true });
    });
});
```

If you are using the simply **ngRoute**, you must to remove your the currentTemplate from templateCache and the return $route.reload() in a $timout!

Comment: Regarding UI Router part, I don't see how this supplements existing answers. And for ngRoute some explanation may be beneficial, I'm not sure that ruining template cache can help.

Comment: In your example you don't exec **event.preventDefault**, required if the event is attached on a link object.

For ngRoute, instead, this is a known issue... so, if you want to force the route reloading you have to remove the current-route-template from templateCache

Comment: [e.preventDefault is done by $location](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/ng/location.js#L889), that's why it isn't in original snippet. I'm not sure that messing with templateCache will change something, please, provide a plunker if it is true.

Comment: try in your application, you can vote me down if doesn't work!